# How to take high quality videos/photos in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, camera

How can I improve the camera quality? I want to take a pic/vid that shows up in fullscreen? If I set the session preset to AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto it's high quality and fullscreen but just for photos and not for videos. I've tried everything else but nothing works.
Currently, it looks like this:

[image]

> EDIT

Why looks my picture like that?
[image]

```
@IBAction func takePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
    var imageViewBackground: UIImageView!
    self.fullScreenView.hidden = false
    self.recordButton.enabled = false
    self.takephoto.enabled = false
    self.recordButton.hidden = true
    self.takephoto.hidden = true

    session.startRunning()

    // add the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to the view and sets the view in fullscreen
    fullScreenView.frame = view.bounds
    videoPreviewLayer.frame = fullScreenView.bounds
    fullScreenView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer)

    // add action to fullScreenView
    gestureFullScreenView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.takePhoto(_:)))
    self.fullScreenView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureFullScreenView)

    // add action to myView
    gestureView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.setFrontpage(_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureView)

    if (preview == true) {
        if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
            // code for photo capture goes here...

            stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: { (sampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
                // process the image data (sampleBuffer) here to get an image file we can put in our view

                if (sampleBuffer != nil) {
                    let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                    let dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
                    let cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault)
                    let image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)

                    self.fullScreenView.hidden = true
                    self.fullScreenView.gestureRecognizers?.forEach(self.fullScreenView.removeGestureRecognizer)
                    self.session.stopRunning()

                    // save image to the library
                    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)

                    imageViewBackground = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.width, self.height))
                    imageViewBackground.image = image
                    imageViewBackground.tag = self.key

                    self.view.addSubview(imageViewBackground)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

Then you need to set you video gravity for full screen to work.

```
captureVideoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
```

Comment: Doesn't work for iPad if I want the picture in fullscreen

Comment: I just tested it on an Air 2 and it goes indeed work.  What are you using?

Comment: I edited my post, now you see how it looks like for me

Comment: what you see on the photo is a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer and I want to display it in fullscreen. With AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh it isn't fullscreen otherwise with AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 it isn't high resolution but fullscreen

Comment: You can set the frame of the preview later do be anything with any preset.  Just create a full screen UIView and the preview layer to that.

Comment: Hmmm doesn't work anyway.. I have no idea why it worked on your iPad

Comment: Set your video gravity.  I added code to my answer.

Comment: I've had that already and if I don't set the frame of the previewLayer it won't appear so I've no idea what's going wrong

Comment: That's everything I do with my preview:                                  `videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
                videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect` then set the frame and add it to my view

Comment: You don't have the gravity correct. You're missing fill.

Comment: And do you know why my picture looks like this when i set the sessionPreset to High? I edited my post above with code and the current picture

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118817/discussion-between-mafioso-and-thevalyreangroup).